# Python Web Scraper - limited results per page defined by page JavaScript

Tags: javascript, python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm having trouble getting the full results of searches on this website:
https://www.gasbuddy.com/home?search=67401&fuel=1
This link is one of the search results I'm having trouble with. The problem is that it only displays the first 10 results (I know, that's a common issue that has been described in multiple threads on stackoverflow - but the solutions found elsewhere haven't worked here.)
The page's html seems to be generated by a javascript function, which doesn't embed all of the results into the page. I've tried using a function to access the link provided in the "More [...] Gas Prices" button, but that doesn't yield the full results either. 
Is there a way to access this full list, or am I out of luck?

Here's the Python I'm using to get the information:

```
# Gets the prices from gasbuddy based on the zip code.
def get_prices(zip_code, store): 
    search = zip_code
    # Establishes the search params to be passed to the website.
    params ={'search': search, 'fuel': 1}
    # Contacts website and make the search.  
    r = requests.get('https://www.gasbuddy.com/home', params=params, cookies={'DISPLAYNUM': '100000000'}) 
    # Turn the results of the above into Beautiful Soup object.
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser') 
    # Searches out the div that contains the gas station information.
    results = soup.findAll('div', {'class': 'styles__stationListItem___xKFP_'})
```

Comment: Changing url to fuel=2 seems to paginate. Why is that not a viable solution?

Comment: To interact with the web page, you need to use a library called `selenium`. It's pretty easy to use. This library mimics the behavior of a browser and you can click on the button to produce more results. It's a great tool to have in your skill-kit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [selenium](http://chromedriver.chromium.org/getting-started). It's a little bit of work to set up, but it sounds like it's what you need.

[Here](https://github.com/lmeninato/GoFundMe/blob/master/python/get_categories_and_urls.py) I used it to click on a website's "show more" button. See more at my exact project.

```
from selenium import webdriver
url = 'https://www.gofundme.com/discover'
driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/webdriver/chromedriver.exe')
driver.get(url)
for elem in driver.find_elements_by_link_text('Show all categories'):
        try:
            elem.click()
            print('Succesful click')
        except:
            print('Unsuccesful click')

source = driver.page_source

driver.close()
```

So basically you need to find the name of the element you need to click to show more info, or you need to use a webdriver to scroll down the webpage.

Comment: To download the chrome driver, use the following [link](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.45/). If you are on PC, download `chromedriver_win32.zip`. Then, extract the zip file and put it in this directory `C:/webdriver`